# Linear algebra: "Dress a list L of matrices in Mat2×2(R) such that for every involution M in Mat2×2(R), there exists C^-1MC=A (A involution)

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: The complete "exercise"]

[image: My solution]

I'm doubting myself because I don't use the fact that A is unique, I don't know where to use this information...
I don't really see anything wrong with my proof and statement, however I'm not confident in my answer.
Can anyone see if my reasoning and conclusion is correct?

Comment: I don't see which matrix on your list will be similar to $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0& -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You use the "fact" that $XY=O$ implies $X=O$ or $Y=O$: this is not true. But as you've just supplied an image of your working and not typed it up with mathjax it is too much work for me to type you up a solution.

Comment: Ah, I forgot that when working with matrix XY=0 implies that X or Y is not invertible... too late to correct now..

Comment: Well @sirlddi you could improve your answer, type it and the question up, and edit accordingly. If you don't do that then it's far too much work to comment on your solution and suggest improvements/repairs (since one can't cut and paste).